# Plot Stacked area with ggplot2 return plot without lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, plotly, ggplotly

I'm trying to plot cumulative values as stacked area plot, but in return, the image that I get do not consist stacked area, only background and legends are there. Initially, I thought the function doesn't recognize duplicate dates, so I tried to use group by function but it still return the same result. Does anyone know what is going on here?

The dataset that I'm using can be found on kaggle.
[covid datset](https://www.kaggle.com/josephassaker/covid19-global-dataset?select=worldometer_coronavirus_daily_data.csv)

Update:
I'm able to do `ggplot(aes(..., text = count))` but not:
`ggplot(aes(..., text = comma(count)))` or
`ggplot(aes(..., text = paste(count)))` or
`ggplot(aes(..., text = text))` where `text` is a mutated column

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")

# load packages
pacman::p_load(pacman, installr, rio, dplyr, tidyr, ggplot2, stringr, scales, viridis, hrbrthemes, plotly, htmlwidgets)

daily_covid <- import("./worldometer_coronavirus_daily_data.csv")

daily_covid <- 
    daily_covid %>%
    replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
    mutate(date = as.Date(date))

data <- 
    daily_covid %>%     
    group_by(date) %>% 
    summarise(
        cumulative_total_cases = sum(cumulative_total_cases, na.rm = T),
        cumulative_total_deaths = sum(cumulative_total_deaths, na.rm = T),
    ) %>% # actually na.rm is not needed
    
    gather(categories, count,
           cumulative_total_cases, cumulative_total_deaths) %>% 
        
    # adding this section of code, the dataframe looks fine
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(text = 
               paste(
                   str_to_title(str_replace_all(categories, "_", " ")),
                   "Count:", count
               )
    ) %>% 
    # section end
    
    arrange(date) # this is just to check if text is appended properly
    
data # a small section of this data is shown below this block

# write.csv(data, paste0(out_data_path, "temp.csv"))
# (subset(data, is.na(text))) # enable this to check if something is na

q3 <-                                                  # V here is the problem
    ggplot(data, aes(x=date, y=count, fill=categories, text = text)) +
    geom_area() +
    facet_wrap(~categories, scales = "free_y")
#     scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
#     theme(legend.position="none") +
#     ggtitle("Cumulative Covid Cases Stacked Area plot") +
#     theme_ipsum() +
#     theme(legend.position="none")
q3
#
itrt_q3 <- ggplotly(q3, tooltip = "text")
itrt_q3
```

This is a small piece of the manipulated data `data` shown above

```
"date","categories","count","text"
2020-01-22,"cumulative_total_cases",571,"Cumulative Total Cases Count: 571"
2020-01-22,"cumulative_total_deaths",17,"Cumulative Total Deaths Count: 17"
```

Comment: I think part of the problem is that you have two vary different scales associated with the two values of the categories variable. The max of cases is 300 million and the max of deaths is 1523.  You also have many NA values associated with deaths. Add in facet_wrap(~categories, scales = "free_y") after geom_area() and you will be able to see the problem.

Comment: Use this to fix the problem with the NA: cumulative_total_deaths = sum(cumulative_total_deaths, na.rm = TRUE).  Then you will get your plot.

Comment: I've experiment with it, na can indeed cause the same problem, but I also found out that I can't use the `ggplot(aes(...., text = text))` field and some other cases is added into the question.

Comment: found the solution, simply just `ggplot(aes(..., group = categories, text = text))`

Answer (score 0):

After you add na.rm = TRUE the graph should print.

[image: pic]

```
data <- 
    daily_covid %>% 
    
    group_by(date) %>% 
    summarise(
        cumulative_total_cases = sum(cumulative_total_cases),
        cumulative_total_deaths = sum(cumulative_total_deaths, na.rm = TRUE),
    ) %>%
    
    mutate(text = 
               paste(
                   "Cumulative Cases:",
                   cumulative_total_cases,
                   "\nCumulative Deaths:",
                   cumulative_total_deaths
               )
    ) %>% 
    
    gather(categories, count,
           cumulative_total_cases, cumulative_total_deaths) %>% 
    
    ungroup() %>% 
    arrange(date) %>% 
    group_by(date, text, categories) 
    
    
data %>%    
    ggplot(aes(x=date, y=count, fill=categories)) +
    geom_area()
```

Comment: now I know na values can cause the same problem, but when I try to make it interactive using ggplotly, as ggplotly require another column that contains text to display on hover, thus I've created a column called text,  but whenever I place that column into `ggplot (aes(..., text = text))` the plot fails to work.

Comment: I've added some more information to the question

Comment: found the solution, simply just `ggplot(aes(..., group = categories, text = text))`